# Can't Get Google Analytics Funnel To Work

Tags: google-analytics

Here is my funnel setup :

Equals to - /partners/getstarted
   Funnel - On
   Step 1 - /partners/sign_up
   Required - Yes

When I paste the paths into the search box on Site Content -> All - the correct pages show up.

Both the pages are getting traffic and I can see users are clicking from signup to get started.  However the funnel is completely blank with no sessions and 0% conversion rate.  Any ideas?

Check out the sign_up page in question here - https://www.upshare.co/partners/sign_up

Comment: If you just created the goal, then you won't be able to see conversions right away in your standard reports. You usually have to wait at least 24 hours. Have you checked in Real-Time reports to see if you can see the goal conversion? What does it say when you validate your goal?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics funnels are really wonky - easiest thing is to use regular expressions and escape the forward slashes properly.

So your first step expression is "partners/getstarted" and your second is "partners/sign_up" (no quotes).

More on regular expressions here (in Ruby, but same logic for GA) - www.rubular.com

Funnels are pretty dangerous to use on Google Analytics though - if your page URLs or site structure changes, you'll blow up your analytics - better to use a server-side tracking tool with really strong funnel visualization (I'm biased, but check out [Indicative](http://www.indicative.com/) for strong server-side analytics and funnels)

Comment: I have added regular expressions with the following paths:

Step 1 - ^/partners/sign\_up$
Destination - ^/partners/getstarted$

But the funnel still isnt working.  Is there any chance you could help with this directly, I'd be happy to pay you for your time.  Please get in touch at simon . turner0 [at] gmail . com

Comment: Take out the carat character and dollar sign - those aren't necessary.

Regex should be:  "partners\/sign_up" and "partners\/getstarted" (no quotes).

Also when you're ready to upgrade your analytics tool check out [Indicative](http://www.indicative.com) - you can reach me there as well.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I've changed the regex to what you've suggsted but the funnel is still blank.  I've just emailed your support inbox at indicative.